# Hadoop / Spark Read Many CSV files

Tags: python, csv, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I have a lot of structured data stored in a very meaningful way and I want to process it in an equally meaning full and efficient way.

```
+- some-hdfs-path/
  +- level-1_var-01/
  |  +- level-2_var-001.csv
  |  +- ...
  |  +- level-2_var-nnn.csv
  +- level-1_var-02/
  |  +- level-2_other-001.csv
  |  +- ...
  |  +- level-2_other-mmm.csv
  +- ... /
  +- level-1_var-nn/
  |  +- ...
```

Each file is around 100MB and has around 1,000,000 rows. The number of files, typically around 100, varies in each directory and so do the file names. In other words, I don't know how many files or what they are called, but I do need their names, and obviously their content.

I am having trouble dealing with the RDDs I am getting from back from `sc.textFile("/some-hdfs-path/level-1_var-01/*.csv")` and `sc.wholeTextFiles("/some-hdfs-path/level-1_var-01")`.

The general goal is to actually get the first and last row from each file in the level-1_var/ directories. Combine the results for each level-1_var, then go back and write out whole new set of files for each level-1_var/ in some-other-hdfs-path/level-1-var/

I am new to Hadoop/Spark and using RDDs. I have read the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html) for the above two functions but I am still confused on how to iterate over the RDDs I'm getting back and do the processing.

EDIT: The files contain time series data, so concatenating the contents of the files in each directory is undesirable. I am open to adding the contents of the files as additional columns to one giant dataframe, but not as rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to read CSV in pySpark by replacing your configurations and properties.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row

def get_first_and_last(filename):
    #rdd variable holds the content of file(it's distributed)
    rdd = spark.read.csv(filename, header=True, mode="DROPMALFORMED").rdd

    #Here filename holds abs path. Feel free to substring as per your needs 
    return Row(filename, rdd.first, rdd.take(rdd.count()).last())


spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Read CSVs") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()

# This file list is not distributed one, It holds list of filenames only
filesList = spark.sparkContext\
    .wholeTextFiles("/some-hdfs-path/level-*_var-*/*.csv")\
    .map(lambda x: x[0])\  
    .collect()

#output array
records = filesList.map(get_first_and_last)

for record in records:
    print(record)
```

I have tried the equivalent code in scala and I'm able to see the results as needed.

**Edit:** Added another approach as per the comments.

*NOTE:* Small files are preferred when `sparkContext.wholeTextFiles()` is used, as each file will be loaded fully in memory. [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.wholeTextFiles)

```
records = spark.sparkContext\
    .wholeTextFiles("/some-hdfs-path/level-*_var-*/*.csv")\
    .map(lambda x : Row(x[0], x[1].split("\\n")[0], x[1].split("\\n")[-1]))\

for record in records.collect():
    print(record)
```

[pySpark - SparkSession](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html)

Comment: what does the structure of `df` look like in the case of multiple CSV files?

Comment: `df` structure will depend on `schema` definition. 1) There is no diff spark in reading a CSV or list of CSV files. 2) But schema should be same for all CSV files in a directory if we want to process in a stretch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SparkSession object of spark 2.0 and give directory of csv's follows

```
val df =spark.read.csv(pathOfDirectory)
```

the above df will have data of all csv's in directory

Comment: isn't that scala syntax? ... and doesn't the line ammount to `some_rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("/some-hdfs-path/level-1_var-01")` ? I'm not sure